# How can I use a mix of core and custom Angular Material icons in an ngFor list?

Tags: angular, icons, angular-material, ngfor

Say I have a list of core [Angular Material icons](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview) like so:

```
<md-nav-list>
    <a md-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <md-icon>{{item.icon}}</md-icon>
    </a>
</md-nav-list>
```

But I've defined some custom ones like so:

```
iconRegistry
  .addSvgIcon('blah_icon', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('images/blah.svg'))
```

And custom icons require a different markup structure, like so:

```
<md-icon svgIcon="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
```

How can I use a blend the two in the repeating list?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some sort of flag to say whether or not it's core or custom. You can then use an ngIf to render the DOM

```
<md-nav-list>
    <a md-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <md-icon *ngIf="item.flag">{{item.icon}}</md-icon>
        <md-icon *ngIf="!item.flag" svgIcon="{{item.icon}}"></md-icon>
    </a>
</md-nav-list>
```

Another option would be to use `[innerHTML]` in your template and change the icon string to include the DOM:

```
<md-nav-list>
    <a md-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" [innerHtml]="item.icon"></a>
</md-nav-list>
```

With new `item.icon` being...

`'<md-icon>home</md-icon>'`

or

`'<md-icon svgIcon="blah_icon"></md-icon>'`

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing, though I'm checking for the custom icon name. I consider it a temporary solution, however. Duplicate markup is ugly.

Comment: Other options: use [innerHTML] in your <a md-list-item> and have the two different DOM items as the string or add all the material icons as custom fonts and just render them all with the svgIcon input.

Comment: I see. Would the entire innerHTML string then be stored in the database?

Comment: You could build them in your component typescript using the same logic as the first part of my answer or store the entire string in the database, whichever is preferred. `ngOnInit () { for( let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) { if ( mdicon) { make mdicon string } else { make custom icon string } } }`